# samba not starting on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, samba

I have this output

```
 user123@Matrix-Server:~$ /etc/init.d/samba stop
    bash: /etc/init.d/samba: No such file or directory
    sputnik@Matrix-Server:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/samba restart
    sudo: /etc/init.d/samba: command not found
    user123@Matrix-Server:~$
```

---

```
 user123@Matrix-Server:~$ sudo apt-get install samba smbfs
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    samba is already the newest version.
    smbfs is already the newest version.
    The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
      linux-headers-2.6.32-19-generic linux-headers-2.6.32-19
    Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Samba is composed of two separated daemons:

- **smbd** which provides the file and printer sharing services
- **nmbd** which provides the NetBIOS-to-IP-address name service

to restart completely samba you need to restart both of them so the correct sequence of commands is

```
sudo /etc/init.d/smbd restart
sudo /etc/init.d/nmbd restart
```

or in a more *"ubuntish"* way

```
sudo service smbd restart
sudo service nmbd restart
```

Comment: Thanks. All the guides out there say to start/stop the "samba" service. I saw the smbd and nmbd but wasn't positive if those were what I needed ... are they new in this version or something?

On a related note, how would I check that?

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo /etc/init.d/samba start
```

Try that or try

```
cd /etc/init.d/
sudo ./samba start
```

If that fails as well reinstall samba:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall samba
```

And then try restarting it.

Comment: I checked /etc/init.d directory and see smbd over there and it worked but not samba

Comment: strange. what version of ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

You can also run this on a single line

```
restart smbd && restart nmbd
```

If this won't work opt for Fen0x's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

### update for who using `Raspberry Pi`

1. `samba` command not found

```bash
$ sudo /etc/init.d/samba restart
sudo: /etc/init.d/samba: command not found
```

2. find out the new service name of `samba`

```bash
$ ls -al /etc/init.d/ | grep -E "\ss"
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 2259 Aug  1  2022 samba-ad-dc
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 2224 Apr 15  2018 saned
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 2061 Aug  1  2022 smbd
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4056 Jul  2  2022 ssh
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 1030 Jan 14  2023 sudo
```

3. restart `smbd` service

```bash
$ sudo /etc/init.d/smbd restart
Restarting smbd (via systemctl): smbd.service.

# OR
$ sudo systemctl restart smbd
# OR
$ sudo systemctl restart smbd.service
```

> screenshot

[image]

### refs

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-systemctl-to-manage-systemd-services-and-units